# document.body.removeEventListener not working for removing listener for keypress event

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I am adding a event listener which listens for Escape keypress and closes the image modal, but on Escape keypress image modal closes but event listener do not removes. Here's my code. Please tell me how to come up with this issue.

```
function closeImgModal() {
    imgModal.style.display = "none";
    document.body.style.overflowY = "auto";
    document.body.removeEventListener('keydown', closeImgModal)
}

function openBig(el) {
    document.body.style.overflowY = "hidden";
    imgModal.style.display = "block";
    randomImg.src = el.src;
    document.body.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
        console.log(e);
        if (e.key === "Escape") {
            closeImgModal();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The listener you add has to be the exact same function you added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove a listener the event names need to be the same. You have keyup vs keypress.

The handler function reference also needs to be the same. For that to happen you will need a named function which I created from the anonymous function used in your addEventlistener and called it `handleKeypress`

Now the parameters used for add/remove are identical as required

```
function closeImgModal() {
  imgModal.style.display = "none";
  document.body.style.overflowY = "auto";
  document.body.removeEventListener('keypress', handleKeypress)
}

function handleKeypress(e) {
  console.log(e);
  if (e.key === "Escape") {
    closeImgModal();
  }
}

function openBig(el) {
  document.body.style.overflowY = "hidden";
  imgModal.style.display = "block";
  randomImg.src = el.src;
  document.body.addEventListener('keypress', handleKeypress);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
function closeImgModal() {
    imgModal.style.display = "none";
    document.body.style.overflowY = "auto";
    document.body.removeEventListener('keypress', closeImgModal)
}

function openBig(el) {
    document.body.style.overflowY = "hidden";
    imgModal.style.display = "block";
    randomImg.src = el.src;
    document.body.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
        console.log(e);
        if (e.key === "Escape") {
            closeImgModal();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will still not work, but yes making sure the event names are the same is also a must..  But instead of people trying to figure out what you changed, please explain in your answers.